# Define types for object keys in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, interface, typescript-typings

I am new to typescript, I want to define types for my object keys, I have checked few ways to achieve it but error is not thrown when value of different type is assigned. e.g.

```
interface sectionProp { 
    _type1: String,
    _columnStrechAllowed: Boolean,
    _columnOccupancy: Number,
    is_mandatory: Boolean
}


export class sectionProperties {
  folioSectionContentProp = <sectionProp> {}

  constructor(type?) {
    this.folioSectionContentProp._type1 = type;
    this.folioSectionContentProp._columnStrechAllowed = false;
    this.folioSectionContentProp._columnOccupancy = 6;
    this.folioSectionContentProp.is_mandatory = false;
  }

}

export class createNewSection extends sectionProperties {
  constructor() {
    super("Test") // here I will assign value
 // super(12)     //@ this does not generate any error as well
 // I might assign value by some other way (from object creation) 
 // but I want to know the reason if type is defined then it should 
 // not accept any value other than type 
  }

}

var z = new createNewSection();
console.log(z)
```

PS: I want my object keys type to be defined

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't actually specify a value for the `type` parameter in the constructor of `sectionProperties` so it is assumed to be `any` and any can be assigned from anything and to anything. You need an explicit type annotation:

```
interface sectionProp {
    _type1: String,
    _columnStrechAllowed: Boolean,
    _columnOccupancy: Number,
    is_mandatory: Boolean
}


export class sectionProperties {
    folioSectionContentProp = <sectionProp>{}

    constructor(type: string) {
        this.folioSectionContentProp._type1 = type;
        this.folioSectionContentProp._columnStrechAllowed = false;
        this.folioSectionContentProp._columnOccupancy = 6;
        this.folioSectionContentProp.is_mandatory = false;
    }

}

export class createNewSection extends sectionProperties {
    constructor() {
        super("Test") // here I will assign value
        // super(12)     //would be an error
    }

}
```

You might consider specifying the `noImplicitAny` compiler option to force you to specify types where the compiler can't infer them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If we explicitly defined the type in the constructor than do we need interfaces (where we are defining the types for our keys)? I hope I am not mixing the two. Because if we define type for sectionProperties constructor that case is handled there only.

Comment: @Mohd.Monis Not sure I get what you are trying to say. The `type1` field in `sectionProp` is a string. Do you want to use different types derived from `sectionProp` in derived types such as `createNewSection ` ?

Comment: If I am assigning value like this `z.folioSectionContentProp._type1 = 12` ; it generates error and this is what I required. I mixed the two with constructor calling and not checking the type and by putting type in constructor it checks so I thought what's the use of interface. I got this now. Thanks